# iOS BLE Scanning for AdvertisementData in background when the phone is in Sleep Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, bluetooth-lowenergy, sleep-mode

I'm trying to search if it is possible for iPhone to scan BLE device and read its advertisementData while it is in sleep mode.

For example, continuous scanning as long as it takes and then if a device changes its advertisementData the phone will wake up and fire a local notification. Meaning, the app is running in background mode for x period of time.

Is it possible? Because in android it is.

Comment: It is, but you need to know the specific service you are looking for. You can scan for all services in the background

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried pressing the power button so that the phone will go to sleep state but CBCentralManager went to PoweredOff state right after. Is it natural? Can I make a workaround so that it can still can scan while in sleep state?

Comment: What scanning code are you using?  Have you added the bluetooth-central background mode to your app?

Comment: Yup, I added in plist required background mode "App Communicates using core bluetooth". I have an array of uuid which I will use in scanning.

Comment: `NSArray *uuidArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID], nil];
        
[_centralManagerDelegate scanForPeripheralsWithServices:uuidArray options:options];` this is my scanning code

Comment: What are your `options`? The duplicates key is ignored in the background so if a peripheral has previously been discovered by your app then its discovery will not re-trigger the `didDiscoverPeripheral` delegate method until your app is re-started.  For long-term discovery you should also opt-in to state-restoration but that isn't needed for a simple case running under Xcode.  Is `_centralManagerDelegate` your `CBCentralManager` instance?

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh I see, if I can no longer discover a previously discovered device, this will be the main problem because I have to endlessly scan the devices and see if they're advertisement data has changed in background and when the phone is in sleep mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146501/discussion-between-paulw11-and-jayson-ong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are restrictions on peripheral scanning when your app is running in the background:

- You must specify the service UUIDs you are interested in; you cannot use `nil`
- The duplicate scan option key is not supported. This is probably what is preventing you from achieving your desired result

As the duplicates key is ignored in the background, if a peripheral has previously been discovered by your app then its discovery will not re-trigger the `didDiscoverPeripheral` delegate method until your app is re-started.

For long-term discovery you should also opt-in to state-restoration but that isn't needed for a simple test-case running under Xcode.